#  How to use ':' to break out words in %w'dog:cat:bird' w/o split

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am trying to do `%w'dog:cat:bird'` but I want the character that breaks apart the words to be a : rather than whitespace as `%w` currently does.

I do not want to use `.split` as in the actual code I am using a few different `%` idioms for different needs and I would like to use just one syntax.

Comment: You can't use an alternate value for `%w`, it is space delimited. But the real issue is why would you want to subvert the behavior of an operator? That path only leads to maintenance problems and madness, and, would result in some noise in a code-review. Go with the flow, not against it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked in "The Ruby Programming Language" by Matz and David Flanagan, and it appears that array literals created with %w *must* use spaces to delimit the elements. If you really want to have arrays of strings, delimited by ":", and you don't want to use "split" in the code, I suggest you define a method of your own which will allow you to simulate the desired behavior, maybe something like:

```
class Object
  def w(str)
    str.split(":")
  end
end
```

Then you can write something like:

```
w'a:b:c'
```

Comment: I was searching for a way to override %w but couldn't find it, is it not a method?

Comment: No, it's not a method. It's core syntax.

Comment: I can also define the `def w` outside of any class and it works.  Presumably it's being defined at the Object Class level (all that top level Object is an Object stuff).  As my main use of ruby is in rails, where would I put that definition?

Comment: Yes, you can put "def w" outside of any class. To my way of thinking, though, defining functions at the top level is only good style in single-file scripts. In larger applications, it's better to namespace your methods by putting them in a class. As for where to put the definition: In my Rails projects, I usually have a file called "core_extensions.rb" in /config/initializers. I put extensions to Object, Array, String, etc. in there.

Comment: BTW, another place where it would be appropriate to define functions at the top level is in irb.